# printf %f with 4 decimals and the symbol "%" in the end

Tags: java

I have a vector:

```
p[0]=0.40816269
p[1]=0.37576407
p[2]=0.16324950
p[3]=0.05282373
```

I need to print the values of the vector as percentage with 4 decimals.
I tried:

```
for(int i=0; i<p.length;i++)
{
    System.out.printf("Criterion "+i+" has the weigth=%.4f \n" , p[i]*100);
}
```

which gives me:

```
Criterion 0 has the weigth=40.8163, .....
```

but I want to print:

```
Criterion 0 has the weigth=40.8163 %, .....
```

I cannot add the symbol "%"  in the end of each row. 
If I try:

```
System.out.printf("Criterion "+i+" has the weigth=%.4f %\n" , p[i]*100);
```

or:

```
System.out.printf("Criterion "+i+" has the weigth=%.4f "+"%\n" , p[i]*100);
```

program throws an exception. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escapee the `%` with `%%`:

```
System.out.printf("Criterion "+i+" has the weigth=%.4f %%\n" , p[i]*100);
```

For more information, see the [java.util.Formatter conversions spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Use `%%` to print out a percent sign:

```
System.out.printf("Criterion "+i+" has the weight=%.4f%%\n" , p[i]*100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this:

```
System.out.printf("Criterion %d has the weigth=%.4f%%\n", i, p[i]*100)
```

If you are going to use printf, then use it all the way :)

Answer (score 1):

`"Criterion "+i+" has the weigth=%.4f %%\n"` just add a `%%`.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, but why not

```
System.out.printf("Criterion %d has the weight=%.4f%%\n" , i, p[i]*100);
```

It's a bit odd to use printf to format the float, but not for i..